# MAKE.COM + Airtable connect string data to new linked record (another table)

Tags: automation, airtable, make.com

My tables on airtable:
[image]
.

I have credit  card details arriving as a string from website(elementor)

card:53261033137xxxxx month:07 year:2027 cvv:4xx id:3002xxxxxx
[image]
I Now parse it as Sting to a "credit card" string filed.
[image]

later parse it manually to a linked table:
[image]

**NEED:**
I WANT TO BE ABLE TO PARSE THE DATA DIRECTLY TO THE LINKED RECORD (create a new record)
[image]

Not sure what to do.